# how to get the Compiler error message? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, logging

How can I get the Compiler Error Message if I have the pageUrl?

I tried using the HttpWebRequest class, but I haven't gotten the result yet.

I have collection of pages, that must execute automatically, and if the page fails, I need it to create a log.

Thank you

Comment: Where are you trying to capture and log these errors? On the server as the pages fail, or in an external application that visits the pages and is served the error?

Answer (score 2):

You can catch all application errors in application global class (global.asax) in `Application_Error` handler.

Other way. You can catch exceptions in custom error module as well, just register you module in `<httpModules>` section and implement following function there:

```
void context_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;

        Exception ex = context.Server.GetLastError();
        //... here goes some code
        }
```

Thus you have to ways to catch any error. Other task is to request all pages. As I can see from your post, you've already have such solution.

Comment: You're right, but my logApplication is Service, WinApplication. I can't implement global.asax

Comment: Where do you want to catch exceptions? In remote win application that pokes web server or on web server itself?

Answer (score 1):

```
string pagetext = (new System.Net.WebClient()).DownLoadString(<url>);

//Add a better control here
if(pagetext.Contains("Server Error"))
{
     `enter code here`
 }
```

Comment: I would note that this method is only reading the page, which requires that the error is shown on the page. So this method should only be used if you have your custom errors mode set to "RemoteOnly": `<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/errorPage.aspx"`. Which is the default, but if you have the mode set to "On" you will not be able to read the error from the page, or if you have it "Off" you would be exposing the error message to the web (which would be bad.)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a program to visit the pages, if the response of the request is a HTTP error than you can investigate further.

If you do not want to write your own program to detect errors originating from HTTP  requests, you can use  a testing framework like [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: if i can't get compiler, how i can know one thing - page fail or not with .net?

Comment: edited my post, remember to accept answer and vote post if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I do very little with ASP.NET type stuff.

[ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) might help you a bit.  It's an error logger for ASP.NET projects.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to catch these exceptions? In your website, or in an external application that is crawling a site?

In an external application, using an HttpWebRequest you'd do something like this:

```
string urlToTry = "http://www.example.com/ServerErrorPage.htm";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlToTry);

try
{
  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

  // Process your success response.
}
catch (WebException we)
{
  HttpWebResponse error = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;

  // If you want to log multiple codes, prefer a switch statement.
  if (error.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
  {
    // This is your 500 internal server error, perform logging.
  }
}
```

The [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception_members.aspx) class will give you messages like:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Once you cast them to an HttpWebResponse, you can get at the [StatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx) and perform whatever logging you require.

Comment: Well, you mentioned using the HttpWebRequest, and your question is a bit vague on *where* you are trying to log these errors - when you call the page from somewhere else with an HttpWebRequest, or on the server when a page is requested?